# Remote help for a standard Windows 10 user

Tags: windows-10, remote-access, remote-assistance

I have a colleague - who is geographically remote, so I can't simply visit him in person - who is a standard user on his Windows 10 computer.

He needs administrative privileges for a task, which is why I want to offer some remote help. We connected using (I guess) Quick Assist from Windows. The app is called "Remotehilfe" in German, which translates to "remote help", however, I believe it's Quick Assist.

Connecting works. However, when I want to do something that needs admin-privileges, my screen goes black, and there's no way for me to enter credentials.

Any solutions so far, that I have found, require admin-action at the geographically distant computer. So, catch-22.

Is there any way to get a remote-help session going where I am able to enter admin-credentials

[image]

---

Answers to the comments so far:

- I have the local admin-credentials for the remote machine
- The remote machine is a work-station/PC; hoever, even if it was a laptop it is still geographically distant.
- The discussed solutions I have found on the internet, nothing that I have tried so far, require a change in the way the remote machine does UAC or a change to the group policies of the domain. I can't do the former, and I am reluctant to do the latter.

Comment: Do you manage their laptop? Or is there an IT department that does? Also, you mention "*Any solutions so far, that I have found...*", could you [edit] your question to briefly list the solutions you've tried? That prevents that others suggest something that you've already verified as not working.

Comment: Do you know the admin password for the remote machine?

Comment: Does [Run as admin gives black screen in Quick Assist/TeamViewer - Intune fix](https://www.cloud-boy.be/portfolio/run-as-admin-gives-black-screen-in-quick-assist-teamviewer-intune-fix/)answer your question?

Comment: What is it you need to run as admin? I can't guarantee this but If i know what it is then I may have a solution for you to elavate that specific process through CMD without your screen going black.

Comment: Can you simply restart the remote computer.  When restarted log in as Admin